# Column rang chart is not getting reset when click on legends in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, multiple-columns

I'm tring to achieve,

1. remove shadow when hovered on column range chart
2. the chart is not getting reset when clicking on legends in highchart. Please find the link

[Example Code JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krishnamkollu/1a80qndb/13/)

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true,
  },
  colors: [
    "#105060",
    "#1E8199",
    "#DB9500",
    "#D03D16",
    "#8200A3",
    "#A60040",
    "#3EBEDE",
    "#FCAC6B",
    "#7FE9CE",
    "#FD6FA5",
    "#89E3F9",
    "#E477FF",
  ],

  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },

  xAxis: {

    categories: xAxisCats,

  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      grouping: false,
      showInLegend: true,
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        align: 'center',
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.high - this.point.low ? this.point.high - this.point.low : '';
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: false,
    formatter: function() {
         const category = this.key + ' : ',
          value = this.point.high - this.point.low ? this.point.high - this.point.low : '';
          
          return category + value
         // return this.point.high - this.point.low ? this.point.high - this.point.low : '';
    }
  }...
```

This is the original graph, when we click on legends(i.e, Dept001) chart not getting reset.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In accition to disabling `hover` state, disable also `inactive` state.

   ```
   plotOptions: {
       series: {
           states: {
               inactive: {
                   enabled: false
               },
               hover: {
                   enabled: false
               }
           },
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Disable `ignoreHiddenSeries` option:

   ```
   chart: {
       ...,
       ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
   }
   ```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vn472r18/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.ignoreHiddenSeries

Comment: Thanks, But 2nd point doesn't seem to work, I  still see the gap in the columns range chart when we click on legends. Can you please help with this?

Comment: Hi @Krishnamraju K, Sorry, I didn't understand you. You need to recalculate `x` data for all visible series after click on legend item.